# Simple notation question regarding orthogonality of sines used in solving PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Just to preface by providing the context for the problem leading up to the question, below is a brief paraphrase of setting up the problem.

$$u_{xx} + u_{yy} = x^2-x + y^2 - y; \ \ 0 \le x,y \le 1 \\ BCs \cases{u(0,y) = 0 \\ u(1,y) = 0 \\ u(x,0) = 0 \\ u(x,1) = 0}$$

Using method of eigenfunction expansion, we assume the solution is of the form $$\tag{1} u(x,y)_1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n(y)\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$$ because this solution is satisfied by the BCs with length, L, = 1 since $\sin(n\pi 0) = \sin(n\pi(1)) = 0$ (We could also use $b_n(x) \sin(n\pi y/L)$ since it also satisfies the BCs along y)

Utilizing the *orthogonality of sines*: $$\tag{2} \int_0^L\sin(n\pi x)\sin(m \pi x)dx = \cases{0 & n =/= m \\ \frac{L}{2} & n=m}$$, we can simply plug our solution into the PDE and multiply both sides by $\sin(m\pi x)$ and integrate which gives me the following ODE:

$$\tag{3} b_m'' - m^2\pi^2b_m = \frac{1-(-1)^m}{m\pi}(y^2-y-\frac{2}{m^2\pi^2})$$

The forcing term is a quadratic multiplied by a constant, so using *undetermined coefficients*, we guess a solution of the form $b_p = K(Ax^2 + Bx + C)$.

Solving this ODE yielded the following equation for the coefficients:

$$\tag{4} b_m = \frac{1-(-1)^m}{m^3\pi^3}y(1-y)$$

---

Okay, so here's where I get confused. The orthogonality of sines made it so that we were only able to get non-zero coefficients at $n=m$ so our solution for $b_m$ plugged into our summation over n, would we simply change the notation of the summation or what exactly would happen? I'm thinking plugging in (4) into (1) (which uses m-indices thanks to (2)) would yield:

$$\tag{5}u(x,y)_1 = \sum_{m=1}^\infty b_m(y)\sin(\frac{m\pi x}{L}) = y(1-y)\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1-(-1)^m}{m^3\pi^3}\sin(m\pi x)$$

Or would it retain the n notation and $b_n=0$ for all $n \ne m$ and *that* would be the result of (2)? If it's the latter, then technically $u(x,y) = 0 + 0 + 0 +... +y(1-y)\frac{1-(-1)^m}{m^3\pi^3}\sin(m\pi x) + 0 + 0 + 0 +...$, right? I need to know the specifics because I plan to code out the summation, and the exact specifics matter in that case for knowing exactly how to set it up.

---

EDIT: Rezha Adrian Tanuharja is correct, the correct form is summed across all m, I have verified the results below:

[image: solution]

Also I think I made a mistake in integration, I was off by a factor of 2, so (4) should be $b_m = 2\frac{1-(-1)^m}{m^3\pi^3}y(1-y)$. That aside, here is the code below showing the summation process was indeed over m and I shortened it to 100 iterations.

```
% basic forcing term (homogeneous BCs)
%   u_xx + u_yy = 2x^2 - x + 2y^2 - y; 0<x,y<1
%       u(0,y) = 0, u(1,y) = 0, u(x,0) = 0, u(x,1) = 0
%           u(x,y) = x(1-x)y(1-y)
x = linspace(0,1,11);
y = linspace(0,1,11)';
m = linspace(1,100,101);
K = 2*(1-(-1).^m)./(m*pi);
C = 0;
B = 1./((m*pi).^2);
A = -1./((m*pi).^2);
C_1 = 0;
C_2 = 0;
u = zeros(11,11);
for j = 1:length(y)
    for i = 1:length(x)
        b_p = K.*(A*(y(j)^2) + B*y(j) + C);
        b_h = C_1.*cosh(m*pi.*y(j))+C_2.*sinh(m*pi.*y(j));
        b = b_p + b_h;
        u(i,j) = sum((K.*(A*(y(j)^2)+B*y(j))).*sin(m*pi*x(i))); 
    end
end
u_sol = x.*(1-x).*y.*(1-y)/2;

figure(4)
subplot(1,2,1)
surf(x,y,real(u))
title('$$2y(1-y)\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-(-1)^m}{m^3\pi^3}\sin(m\pi x)$$','Interpreter','LaTex')
subplot(1,2,2)
surf(x,y,u_sol)
title('True solution:$$\frac{x(1-x)y(y-y)}{2}$$','Interpreter','Latex');
```

---

EDIT: Just realized I made a mistake in the equation in my figure. It should be $y(1-y)$ instead of $y(y-y)$

Comment: Just curious, what's the motivation in using the eigenfunction expansion method here? Particularly since the analytical solution $u\left(x,y\right)=0.5xy\left(x-1\right)\left(y-1\right)$ is not difficult to find?

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja To gain experience using this method for pedagogical reasons. I'm teaching myself to use this method for different cases. You are correct, we can guess the solution, but this isn't always a reliable method. As a matter of fact, I created this problem myself using that solution you provided to build the problem and its BCs.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja The next step was using a programming language like Matlab to test the solution obtained using eigenfunction expansions with the solution you mentioned to see if I had done it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting at this part of the post:

> The orthogonality of sines made it so that we were only able to get non-zero coefficients at $n=m$ ...

The statement is misleading. You can get all of the coefficients, you just compute the coefficients one by one (in theory). In practice, you select an arbitrary $m$ and solve for $b_{m}$. Since $m$ is arbitrary, the expression for $b_{m}$ holds for all possible values of $m$:

$$
b_{m}
=
\frac{1-\left(-1\right)^{m}}{m^{3}\pi^{3}}
y\left(1-y\right)
\phantom{x}
\forall
\phantom{x}
m\in\mathbb{N}
$$

Therefore, (5) is correct.

**Remarks**

In the comment you said we can guess the analytical solution. I wouldn't call it guessing, since there are mathematical procedures to obtaining the solution :D

Comment: Thank you! What is the method you used to arrive to the exact solution if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: The homogenous solution is in the form of $axy+bx+cy+d$ and the particular solution from the undetermined coefficients method is $0.5x^{2}y^{2}-0.5x^{2}y-0.5xy^{2}$. Then compute the homogenous solution's coefficients to satisfy the four boundary conditions.

Comment: So using the method of eigenfunction expansion, we turned the Poisson Equation into a 2nd order 1-D linear ODE to solve for $b_m$. I'm guessing you're using some method that keeps it 2-D. So for finding the homogeneous solution to Laplace's Equation $u_{xx}+u_{yy} = 0$, I know we can use method of separation of variables, but that's all I know. Did you use a different method for obtaining the homogeneous part? Sorry that probably doesn't make sense given the context. I should have asked how you know the form of the homogeneous solution?

Comment: Okay, so for undetermined coefficients, assuming this is how it's done in 2-D (I don't actually know if this right), since the forcing term is a a sum of x's and y's whose highest power is, n, we assume $u_p = Ax^ny^n+Bx^ny^{n-1}+By^nx^{n-1}+Dx^{n-1}y^{n-1}+...$, which gives us $u_p = Ax^2y^2+Bx^2y+Cxy^2$ and the homogeneuos part is sum of the terms whose power is less than the order of the differential operators. Setting it up this way did work

Comment: Just letting you know I went ahead and verified it, and you were correct about the sum being over m. I have added a plot which verifies this